# How to get a rejected upolad error due to file size limit rule from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have set a rule in firebase storage to limit a user to upload a file not more than 20MB,

```
service firebase.storage {
          match /b/{bucket}/o {
          match /{allPaths=**} {
                     allow write: if request.auth !=null;
                     allow read: if  request.auth !=null
                                      && request.resource.size < 20 * 1024 * 1024;
                               }
                              }
                          }
```

This works fine,but the problem is when the video is rejected by the server due for over limit there's no listener to get that message or error.

I have try the following with no success

```
       UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("VideoText")
                .child(VideoIdentifire)
                .putFile(SendVideo);
        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                long progress = 0;
                progress = (long) (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Uploading is " + progress + "% done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }
              })

                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fail" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCanceled() {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })

                .addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPaused(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                })

                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

               }
                });
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: 1) Please edit the question to also show the API call that returns the `Task` to which you add these listeners. 2) Also include what exactly happens when you run this code. Does the file get written on the server? Is any listener called? What line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do? Unless you tell us these things, there's no way for us to know exactly what's going wrong, which makes it much harder to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ,basically everything works fine with the above code, but the only issue is that, I have set rule in the firebase storage server that the user shouldn't upload  a file with 20MB and above. When file is rejected I cannot get a message from the server showing the rejection, I tried the above listener none of them worked. I expected OnFailureListener to return that the video failed to upload but it does not.

Comment: Does *any* of your listeners get called when the upload completes/fails (note that your `onSuccess` is empty, so that'll be hard to spot)? If not, can you try [`addOnCompleteListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTask#addOnCompleteListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener%3CResultT%3E)) to see if that at least fires?

Comment: yes OnSuccess get called and I can get the uri from there i have remove the code here on that cause it is too long,also onProgress get called and i can monitor while upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are rejecting **read** operations of resources that are larger than 20MB, while your code is **writing** a file. To reject a **write** operation, you'll want to add the size check to the write rule (too):

```
 allow write: if request.auth !=null;
                  && request.resource.size < 20 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen, I don't know how did I missed that. Now onFailure get called. Funny enough I wonder why was the file still being rejected by the server when the rule was set on read instead of write.!?

Comment: Reads of large files would be rejected with your original rules, writes wouldn't.